# Ubuntu 14.04 is very slow to respond while Handbrake is encoding

Tags: 14.04, handbrake

I've upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 install to 14.04 using a fresh install.

I have Handbrake installed using it's nightly PPA. and ever since I've been running it on 14.04, while using it to encode video files, the entire computer becomes unresponsive and very slow.

I checked in the System Monitor and handbrake's instance has a "normal" priority, and even if I change it to "very low" priority, the system is still extremely slow.

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What are your computer specs? Specifically CPU, RAM, and HD.

Comment: I'm having the same problem since 14.04 (no problems with 13.10). In the Handbrake Forums there is already [a thread regarding this issue](https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=30021). It doesn't seem to be just an issue of the high CPU load. I also confirmed that by running a CPU torture test (Prime95) - which, in contrast to Handbrake, did not have a significant impact on my GUI performance. According to the link above the Handbrake CLI version also seems to work without this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable the "Show system tray icon" option in "File -> Preferences" (the little icon which shows you the completion percentage while a job is running).

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that with the "Show system tray icon" box unchecked (it is checked by default), the desktop returns to normal operation.  however that may just be fixing the symptom, in the sense that the desktop is working well now, but not the problem.

With this option enabled in "Preferences", and nothing else of any note running, the Compiz process goes from 1% to about 18% of CPU time (on my system).  This is a huge amount of processor time devoted to updating one small app. indicator/icon.

So I think the problem is somewhere between Compiz and the Handbrake Icon/App Indicator.

System Specs: Quad Core 3.3 GHz i5 CPU, 8 Gb RAM, Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty w. Unity desktop.